# I can't install symfony2 feature to eclipse from symfony dubture com - strange error

Tags: eclipse, symfony, eclipse-kepler

I try to install Symfony2 Feature to Eclipse Kepler (I tried to 32-bit and 64-bit version as well) but I have only this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Symfony Feature 1.0.85 (com.dubture.symfony.feature.feature.group 1.0.85)
  Missing requirement: Twig Editor Feature 1.0.109 (com.dubture.twig.feature.feature.group 1.0.109) requires 'org.eclipse.php 0.0.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Symfony Feature 1.0.85 (com.dubture.symfony.feature.feature.group 1.0.85)
  To: com.dubture.twig.feature.feature.group 1.0.109
```

I have installed a PDT.

Does someone know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

'org.eclipse.php' was removed as of PDT 3.1.2.
Go to http://symfony.dubture.com/installation/ and try Latest Milestone(it is 1.0.94 now).